# Replace newline with break in email using AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

I have a Data Extension with some text fields. In the text fields have copy text with newlines.

When I output this copy text when rendering the email I would like to replace the newlines from the Data Extension fields into with `<br/>`.

Is there any workaround with AMPScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [**replace()**](https://ampscript.guide/replace) AMPscript function:

```
%%[

var @copyText, @copyTextAdj
set @copyText = AttributeValue("copyText")
set @copyTextAdj = replace(replace(@copyText ,char(13),""), char(10),"<br/>")

]%%
Original:%%=v(@copyText)=%%
<br>Adjusted: %%=v(@copyTextAdj)=%%
```

**Reference:**

[**Function Index**](https://ampscript.guide/function-index/)

Comment: Hello Adam, thanks a lot. But this doesn't work for me. But i solved it with SSJS.

Comment: Updated my example to replace carriage return and linefeed.

Comment: thanks Adam. Its working now. And thanks for the hint of overhead processing.

Answer (score 1):

I solved that issue with SSJS:

```
var text = Variable.GetValue("@copytext");
var newtext = text.replace(/[\r\n]/g,"
");
//Set the Variable to be accessible in AMPscript
Variable.SetValue("@newcopytext",newtext);
```

Comment: There's extra overhead processing with SSJS in an email.  AMPScript is a better choice -- if you have the option.